# Newtonsoft Json how to only take Value section

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, .net-core

On my API side, I use JsonConvert.SerializeObject() to set it to a string. This is the output from my API:

> {"ContentType":null,"SerializerSettings":null,"StatusCode":null,"Value":{"draw":1,"recordsTotal":0,"recordsFiltered":0,"data":[],"order":null,"orderdir":null}}

This is what the API looks like:

```
[HttpPost("Preview")]
public JsonResult Preview([FromBody]AnnouncementAccessPreviewRequestViewModel svm)
{
    ApiResponseViewModel arvm = new ApiResponseViewModel();
    var res = announcementData.Preview(svm.SearchViewModel, svm.TenantId);
    arvm.IsSuccessful = true;
    arvm.Message = null;
    arvm.Output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(res);
    return Json(arvm);
}
```

arvm.Output is a string

How can I only take the Value section from the output?

Comment: Shouldnt you be able to do something like res.Value or JsonConvert.SerializeObject(res).Value ??

Comment: Unfortunately not. There is no value word there.

Comment: Perhaps then create a proxy object from the API, bc if it returns a string, makes little sense to use json if you dont get a object from it no?

Comment: The API returns a JsonResult. WIthin the JsonResult, arvm.Output is another Json String.

Comment: I just need the data within the values without the additional properties.

Comment: Again if you have a Json string saved somewhere, I would Deserialize it in order to get an object, and then its very easy to extract the Value field, bc its an objects, and objects are very easy to handle and use.

Comment: The question is unclear. Please provide an expected output in the question. If you want to have serialized Value property within ApiResponseViewModel, then use JsonConvert.SerializeObject(res.Value), otherwise update your question.

Comment: I realized what I have done wrong.  When I was serializing my data from the API side, I should have taken the value instead of the whole thing. Thank you for helping me realize it.

Comment: Even if you took the whole thing a json string should be deserialized to an object, Which is just one additional line in order for you to access the desired member property of the object. Also can you edit your code so I can see how you achieved this.

Answer (score 0):

That's how I solved it when I had this problem.
private YourModel GetJsonObject()

```
   var parsedObject = JObject.Parse(resultContent);
   string p = parsedObject.ToString();
   if (p.Contains("Succes"))
      {
       string popupJson = JObject.Parse(parsedObject["data"].ToString()).ToString();
       YourModel= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourModel>(popupJson);
       return YourModel;
       }
```

There is a side way to get this model from https://json2csharp.com/.

Answer (score -1):

you can try this

```
   var output=JObject.Parse(json);
   
   Value value=output["Value"].ToObject<Value>();
```

class

```
public class Value
{
    public int draw { get; set; }
    public int recordsTotal { get; set; }
    public int recordsFiltered { get; set; }
    public List<object> data { get; set; }
    public object order { get; set; }
    public string orderdir { get; set; }
}
```

or if you can change Api

```
public JsonResult Preview([FromBody]AnnouncementAccessPreviewRequestViewModel svm)
{
       var res = announcementData.Preview(svm.SearchViewModel, svm.TenantId);
    
    var output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(res);
    return Json(output);
}
```

but the right way is

```
public IActionResult Preview([FromBody]AnnouncementAccessPreviewRequestViewModel svm)
{
    return announcementData.Preview(svm.SearchViewModel, svm.TenantId);
}
```

in this case you don't need to serialize or deserialize